# How to get a field of a foreign key Model appear in a Django-Serializer?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization

I am building a Django application that exposes a REST API by which users can query 2 of my application's models. I'm following the instructions [**here**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart#quickstart).

My two models are:

1. The Django User model from django.contrib.auth
2. The model shown below.

   ```
   class Profile(models.Model):  
       user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   ```

My Serialiazers are as follows:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', )

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'slug', 'user',)
```

I can see that this is working when I hit the APIs from the command-line:

```
% curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u root:MyPassword http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/profiles/60/
{
    "id": 60,
    "slug": "myprofile",
    "user": "http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/users/16/"
}

% curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -uroot:MyPassword http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/users/16/
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/users/16/",
    "username": "myUser",
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
}
```

What I would like to know are two things:

1. How do I change my Profile's serializer such that the user's username appears in the serialized profile?
2. How can I expose this API publicly so it works even without the root/password login?

Comment: Same question posted here last year, unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649522/serializing-a-model-which-has-a-foreign-key-to-django-auth-user?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Question #1 Answered correctly here: [How to include in queryset details fields of a foreign key (django and rest_api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040750/how-to-include-in-queryset-details-fields-of-a-foreign-key-django-and-rest-api?rq=1)

Question #2 Re-asked more clearly here: [How are permissions to access to Django REST API managed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004281/how-are-permissions-to-access-to-django-rest-api-managed)