# How are permissions to access to Django REST API managed?

Tags: python, django, rest

I am building a Django application that exposes a REST API by which users can query my application's models. I'm following the instructions **[here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart#testing-our-api)**.

Below you can see me hitting this API from the command line with various username/passwords.
However, it only works If I use the root user and password. Why? How do I change that? I have not specified anywhere that this API is only available to the root user. I want it to be publicly available

```
% curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u root:myRootPassword http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/profiles/60/
{
    "id": 60,
    "slug": "my_user",
    "user": "http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/users/16/"
}

% curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/users/16/
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

% curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4'  -u myUser:myPassword http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/profiles/60/
{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}

% curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4'   -u myUser:myPassword http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/profiles/60/
{
    "detail": "Invalid username/password"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your APIView, or your ModelViewSet do

```
permission_classes = []
```

or

```
permission_classes = [rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny]
```

This will make it publicaly available for any one. This is because all modeviewsets/viewsets/ or APIViews all inheirit from APIView which sets the permission classes to

```
permission_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES
```

Which I'm guessing in your case is only a superuser.

OK Just looked at the guide you're following. If you look at your settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',),
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10
}
```

Your setting the default permission class to be only admins.  So you can either do what I suggested earlier and override the default permissions, or change IsAdminUser to

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10
}
```

Good luck, django-rest-framework is amazing.